# Raspberry Pi and I2C in c++ with wiringPi for PCF8591

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to understand I2C bus for controlling a PCF8591 D/A Converter with the wiringPi C library on my Raspberry Pi B+.

I wrote a test code (in c++) which work fine, but I don't know if I'm doing it the right way. The program reads and display the 4 analog input values each 0.5 seconds, and set the output accordingly to the average value of the 4 inputs pins.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>

using namespace std;

int readInput(int fd, int reg)
{
    wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, reg);
    return wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, reg);
}

int main()
{
    wiringPiSetupGpio();
    int dacModule = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x48);
    if (dacModule < 0)
    {
        cout << "I2C Setup Error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int i;
    int A[4]        = {0,       0,      0,      0};
    int A_Reg[4]    = {0x40,    0x41,   0x42,   0x43};

    while (1)
    {
        for (i=0;i<4;i++) A[i] = readInput(dacModule, A_Reg[i]);

        wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(dacModule, 0x40, (A[0]+A[1]+A[2]+A[3])/4);

        cout << endl;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++) cout << i << " : " << A[i] << endl;
        delay(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are :

- I noticed I need to call the wiringPiI2CReadReg8 function twice in order to read the correct input value, why ? (If I don't do so, the function return the previous input value).
- I read there is a special module of the wiringPi library specially made for the PCF8591 ([This one](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=51867)), is there any performance differences between the two approach (special lib vs generic I2C lib) ?

Thanks a lot for your help / feedbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question: yes, that's normal. If you look to the datasheet (which you can find [here](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pcf8591&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocuments%2Fdata_sheet%2FPCF8591.pdf&ei=7aL3VKPhBMn1OOGKgfgG&usg=AFQjCNE4s_AxyUTglSTDJHzmF0qwh3x4sw&sig2=-G0qlbFJeA04kWpkW2TnbQ&bvm=bv.87519884,d.ZWU%20%22here%22))), you will see in figure 8 on page 8 that a read action is triggering a new conversion but will output the result of the **previous** conversion.  So, you indeed need to read out 2 bytes if you want to know the *current* conversion by "forcing" two consecutive read actions one after the other.
It's also again mentioned on the next page, second paragraph.

As for your second question, I have no experience yet with that library.  But the source code is freely available, so you could check and compare your code/method with what you find in there.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code for PCF8591 using a C language.
This cord work fine.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
cc -o test1 test1.c -lwiringPi
*/

int main (void)
{
  int fd;
  int i;
  int a2dChannel = 0; // analog channel
  int a2dVal;
  float a2dVol;
  float Vref = 3.3;

  if ((fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x48)) < 0) {
    printf("wiringPiI2CSetup failed:\n");
  }

  for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    wiringPiI2CWrite(fd,0x40 | a2dChannel);
    a2dVal = wiringPiI2CRead(fd); // Previously byte
    a2dVal = wiringPiI2CRead(fd);
    a2dVol = a2dVal * Vref / 255;
    printf("a2dVal=%d\n",a2dVal);
    printf("a2dVol=%f[V]\n",a2dVol);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

And you can use analogRead().

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcf8591.h>

#define PINBASE 100

/*
cc -o test2 test2.c -lwiringPi
*/

int main (void)
{
  int i;
  int a2dChannel = 0; // analog channel
  int a2dVal;
  float a2dVol;
  float Vref = 3.3;

  if (pcf8591Setup(PINBASE, 0x48) < 0)
  {
    printf("pcf8591Setup failed:\n");
  }

  for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    a2dVal = analogRead(PINBASE + a2dChannel);
    a2dVol = a2dVal * Vref / 255;
    printf("a2dVal=%d\n",a2dVal);
    printf("a2dVol=%f[V]\n",a2dVol);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```